# What does M-theory predict at the singularity of a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, string-theory, quantum-gravity, singularities

how does M-theory avoid problems like infinite density and geodesic incompleteness.
like, is there a fundamental limit to where matter can collapse or simply does matter decay and form a condensate of some boson.

Comment: Essential duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/264141/50583